# ReactJS for loop create buttons and set variable according to the integer in the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, I am trying to create 10 buttons with for loops, and set a variable with the integer from the for loop, however the function setMqty(i) always returns 11 for all the buttons. What is the correct way for doing this?

```
  var qtyButtons = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    qtyButtons.push(<div
        onClick={(btn) => {qtyBtnToggle(btn);setMqty(i); }}
    >
      {i}
    </div>)
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am guessing setMqty is a state .can you try setMqty(currentValue=> currentValue+1)

Comment: `setMqty(i)` always passes the last value of `i`, because `for (var i = 1;` uses a single `i` for all iterations. So whenever the callback is invoked they all refer to the same `i`, which is `11` after the loop is over. Use `let` instead of `var`. `for (let i = 1;` will create a separate `i` for each iteration. See: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Nice @3limin4t0r Thanks mate, it works now, such a simple solution! Please put this as an answer and I will accept it gladly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here has to do with scoping. Let me reduce your example to a more minimal example:

```js
var qtyCallbacks = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  qtyCallbacks.push(() => console.log(i));
}

for (const callback of qtyCallbacks) {
  callback();
}
```

What's going wrong here? Why is it only logging `11` and not `1-10`?

The issue is that a variable defined with `var` are scoped to the nearest function or globally if not in a function. So what does this mean?

It means that each iteration in your for loop refers to the same `i`. This isn't an issue if you directly use `i`.

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  console.log(i); // logs 1-10
}
```

However it does become an issue if you refer to `i` in code that is executed at a later point. The reason the initial snippet only logs `11` is because all the callbacks are created, each one referring to the same `i`. So when you evoke each callback after the for-loop is complete, they will all refer to the current value (which is `11`).

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
}

console.log(i); // logs 11
// so if we invoke the callbacks here they all log 11
```

So how do you solve this issue? The simplest solution is probably to replace `var` with `let`. `let` will create a new variable for each for-iteration. Meaning that each created callback will refer to their own `i` and not a shared `i`. This also means that you cannot access `i` outside of the for-loop.

```js
var qtyCallbacks = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  qtyCallbacks.push(() => console.log(i));
}

for (const callback of qtyCallbacks) {
  callback();
}

console.log(i); // expected error, `i` is only available within the for-block
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very comprehensive answer sir! Hope this will help others too :)

Answer (score 1):

I think using a map function is the correct way for doing it.

Therefore, you must generate a range of numbers our any element to be able to perform a map function.

So if i was in your place i would have do it like:

```
const [mqty, setMqty] = useState(0);

// ...

const qtyButtons = Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => {
  const value = parseInt(i);

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick(value)}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
});

// ...
// The trick here is that function returning another function, beware of that
const handleClick = (i) => () => {
  setMqty(i);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing setMqty is a state.Can you try

```
setMqty(currentValue=> currentValue+1)
```